# When activating PHP-FPM does the recommended 30MB of RAM per domain apply to each worker per domain?

Tags: php, apache, cpanel

I am activating Apache PHP-FPM. When activating PHP-FPM does the recommended 30MB of RAM per domain apply to each worker per domain?

I have reviewed the cPanel documentation (For cPanel & WHM version 80). The documentation states:

> "Warning: We strongly recommend that you only activate Apache PHP-FPM if your server has at least 2 GB of RAM available, or at least 30 MB of RAM per domain. If you enable PHP-FPM on a server with less than the required RAM, your server may experience severe performance issues."